# spring test log4j error

Tags: spring-mvc, testing

I get this error on my controller tests on Spring MVC project:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at es.juntaex.asamblea.tests.controllers.LegislaturaControllerTest.testList(LegislaturaControllerTest.java:37)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
>       at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)

The test file content:

```
package com.projects.myproject.tests.controllers;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LegislaturaControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testList() throws Exception {   
        mockMvc.perform(get("/clientes/list"));
    }
}
```

My pom.xml dependencies content is:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j13</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>es.juntaex.asambleadata</groupId>
    <artifactId>asamblea-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Please, could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mockMvc object was not intialized in your issue.
add @Mock annotation on top of the field.

```
@Mock
MockMvc mockMvc;
```

setup the mocks by adding,

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
}
```

after that it will be great if you check all objects are present or not before run the test methods by adding

```
@Test
public void testMock() {
    assertNotNull(mockMvc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Confuser, I get another error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.log(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
 at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:84)
 at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.debug(SLF4JLog.java:128)
 at org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources.addLast(MutablePropertySources.java:106)
 at

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
 at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)

Comment: You can remove @Mock annotation on top of MockMvc and try.

Comment: I don't know if I have troubles with log4j version:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.log(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
 at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:84)

Comment: Didn't get exact problem @Pako Gonzalez, can you remove slf4j-log4j dependency and add slf4j-api of version 1.7.25?

Comment: The problem is in this line:

this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mycontroller).build();

When I uncomment this line always show me log4j error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.Logger.log(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
 at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:84)
 at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.debug(SLF4JLog.java:128)

Comment: Ok that was great. I think the problem is that you cannot annotate your controller object with @InjectMocks?. can you try it with @InjectMocks MyController controller;

Comment: @InjectMocks annotation injects the mock objects into the class.

Comment: run the test case without log4j. This way at least we can confirm that the problem is with log4j or not?

Comment: Solved! The problem was with slf4j version in dependency project, there was conflicts with both versions.

Comment: That was great to hear. and it is already mentioned in my second comment. anyway, good to hear as solved.